# PHP - insert process on another domain

Tags: php

I have this condition,  there is 2 site with its own database and domain. in this site, there is a form which the data save on database C on another domain.

is there any way to make the "insert process" be on domain C, because after the insert process the data will send via email to a certain address.

I thought to make function on domain C, and call the function in the site(A or B) to run the insert process. but I dont know how to do it.
or is there any way to do it.

sorry for bad english

Comment: Theoretically its possible to just make another connection to the remote database, but most if not all hosts will deny remote access to their databases.

Comment: What you want to do is called "webservice". Search that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using both site on same server then just make database connection for other database and execute query using this connection for insertion and other connection to access data from current database. and if you are running application on different different server then use Web Service (REST/SOAP) to communicate between application .

Comment: actually I tried to simplify the process, cause after the insert process, the data will be send via email to a multiple address with different format. so I want to centralize the whole process in 1 place.

Answer (score 1):

give the ip of domain c machine in your connect code and it's specified database...

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very vague / complicated. It would be easier with an example.

It sounds as if you are to do cross site scripting. This could be achieved in 2 ways :

Javascript:

```
<script>
  window.location='http://tagerget.com/?foo='+bar
</script>
```

Serverside :

```
 curl --request POST 'http://www.somedomain.com/'
```

curl can be called from php and many other languages.

Ofcourse the targeted server must allow cross site scripting from the source domain otherwise this could be abused to hack websites etc..

Besides that you have many more options of calling a database directly or setting up an API/webservice trough REST/RPC Json/SOAP etc

Comment: sorry for the vague question. because honestly I don't really know what I'm looking for. would you mind to tell me what I'm looking for with your own perspective ?

Comment: what is the situation then ? you have data on one server and it needs to be stored on another server ? where is the data coming from and where does it have to be saved ?